# JUnit 4 test failures after Java 11 (Corretto 11) and Spring 5 5.2.13.RELEASE upgrades, "Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Tags: java, junit5, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

As I mentioned in the title, we are migrating from Java8 with JUnit4&5 mixed and Spring4.3.11.RELEASE to Java11 and Spring5.2.13.RELEASE. I have the following maven version 3.8.1 configured under project/build/plugins sections,

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
            <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Some of our JUnit tests are consistently failing now running with Java 11 & 15. All tests are passing as usual with Java 8. I'd tried with a few approaches, the newer tags without success. Did I miss anything or it is a known issue in the newer Spring with Java11? Here the code snippets and stack traces,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyTest.TestConfiguration.class }) 
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFail() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/../someUrl")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }

  @EnableWebMvc
  public static class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyRestController myRestController() {
        return new MyRestController();
    } 
    // multiple service layer @Autowired beans in the call stack
    @Bean
    public static SomeOtherBeanServices someOtherAutoWiredBeanServices() {
        return null; // or return mock(SomeServiceBean.class)
    }
  ...
```

RestController,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/.../someUrl")
public class MyRestController {

@Autowired
private SomeOtherBeanServices someOtherAutoWiredBeanServices;
...
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)  at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)  at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)    at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)    at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
> at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
> at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
> at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
> at
> com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'addLineItemRuleRESTService':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'addLineItemRuleService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'addLineItemRuleService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'itemRuleHelperService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'itemRuleHelperService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.ghx.user.api.IUserService' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> ... 44 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'addLineItemRuleService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'itemRuleHelperService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'itemRuleHelperService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.ghx.user.api.IUserService' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 62 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'itemRuleHelperService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.ghx.user.api.IUserService' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 75 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.ghx.user.api.IUserService' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1312)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 88 more

Comment: It simply states that `IUserService` is not found as a dependency. Is it available through TestConfiguration?

Comment: But these are prod code (java8), if I reset my IDE to java 8, all still passing fine. \@Service \@Transactional public class UserService implements IUserService

Comment: Could it be that your projects are being configured as "modules" in your IDE? If so, that could lead to module-path vs. class-path issues for component scanning.

Comment: Any doc or pointers to read? This might be the bug in spring? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21515

Comment: Also, see a closed duplicate issue of issue 21515, with sample stack trace (exactly the same in this thread) and a workaround at, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18516. This bug is still open.

Comment: I resolved this issue, but not ideal and it seems a bug in Spring that JavaConfig failed to scan from the base package! I basically declare every service beans in TestConfiguration.